# std::unique_ptr<T> without allocating memory on heap

Tags: c++11, unique-ptr

I wrote accidentally a statement like

```
std::unique_ptr<Thing> m_thing; 
m_thing->DoStuff();
```

instead of

```
std::unique_ptr<Thing> m_thing(new Thing);
m_thing->DoStuff();
```

the first example compiles and run, which doesn't make any sense to me because m_thing is not pointing to any object. Here a slightly bigger code example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
class Thing
    {
    public:
    ~Thing(){ std::cout << "destructor of class Thing\n"; }
    void DoStuff(){ std::cout << "doing stuff\n";  }
    };

void Foo()
   {
   std::unique_ptr<Thing> m_thing; 
    m_thing->DoStuff();  //why does this work, since i suppose m_thing to be empty?
    }

int main()
    {
    Foo();
    std::cout << "after Foo()\n"; 
    std::cin.get(); 
    return 0; 
    }
```

Why can the "empty" m_thing unique_ptr invoke the DoStuff()-Method of the Thing-class?
i noticed also, that the destructor of Thing-class never gets invoked when declaring m_thing
with

```
std::unique_ptr<Thing> m_thing;
```

instead of

```
std::unique_ptr<Thing> m_thing(new Thing);
```

I didn't found any explanation of this behaviour via google, so i hope maybe someone can explain to me what is happening here behind the curtains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program exhibits undefined behavior. "Seems to work" is one possible manifestation of undefined behavior. It's morally equivalent to

```
Thing* p = NULL;
p->DoStuff();
```

which I predict would also compile and run. `DoStuff` is called with `NULL` for `this` pointer - but it doesn't actually use `this`, that's why it doesn't crash and burn as you expect.

Answer (score 4):

`DoStuff` isn't virtual and doesn't access any members of your object, so you can get away with calling it (I'm pretty sure this is unspecified behavior though). The default constructor for `unique_ptr` initializes it to `nullptr`, so it doesn't allocate any memory on its own.

Oh, and the destructor of course doesn't get called because unique_ptr doesn't invoke its deleter on `nullptr`s.